Get rotation angle from rotation vector over axis Y/Z
For some of you this could be a really easy question, but I didn't find a solution or was too dumb to understand some of the math papers.
I am currently working in Python but that shouldn't matter.
What I want is to get the rotation angle of the unit vector representing the rotation, over a specific axis.
Example:
I have the Vector (1.0, 0, 0) and I know this represents the rotation over Y-axis.
Or the Vector (0, 0, -1) which is the representation for a rotation over Z-axis.
How do I get the angles represented by these vectors?

Please explain. What do you mean by "Vector (1.0, 0, 0) and I know this represents the rotation over Y-axis" ? If you knew which vector rotated into which vector then you could work out the angle of rotation, but at the moment your question doesn't make sense.

That's all the information I have. I have an Vector, e.g. (1.0, 0, 0) and the description from the manual: "The vector specifies the rotation by means of the y-axis.". So I assume the vector represents some rotation by means of the y-axis, from 0deg to 360deg. That's the point where I am struggeling, how to calculate the angle from the vector.

You have a unit vector in the x direction and you claim it represents a rotation about the y axis? Could you provide a link as to where this peculiar information comes from.

Here is the link: https://ecad-wiki.prostep.org/specifications/kbl/v25-sr1/classes/transformation/

I THINK the Vector (1.0, 0, 0) should represent a rotation in 90deg around the Y-Axis. That would make sense in the use cases I have, but I don't know how to calculate

Your link doesn't contain anything corresponding to your statement. Are you sure that your "vector" isn't really the argument list of some (unspecified) function and nothing to do with vectors at all?

"[...] and the description from the manual" which manual? Your post mentions nothing about a manual, so please click [edit] and update your post to include those details. "I am [...] in Python but that shouldn't matter" of course it matters, show your [mcve] code, including imports, so that folks know what specific code you're working with, and tag your post with the framework(s) you're working with.
